# Ph.D Schools "focusing" on theory

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

There's a rollback extravaganza happening on [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/what-universities-in-the-united-states-or-in-europe-have-a-phd-focus-in-theoretic). There are a number of problems in the question, and foolishly I contributed to this by even answering.

1. There are multiple questions within the question, and they are quite different from each other and should have been separated out
2. On the question of universities with a "focus" on theory, there's a clear ambiguity. If the question was asking for places where one could apply directly into a TCS program, then it makes sense (because not many places have this option). That was my intent in answering. However, if the question was asking for places that have a strong theory group (whatever that means) then it's completely out of bounds for our site.

My feeling is that given the massive editing and re-editing happening on the answer (by our mods, no less!), we need to shift all discussion here. My personal preference is that this question be closed, and if the OP wishes to ask a set of very specific questions they may do so.

Comment: The large amount of editing was not a bad thing, in principle, as we were all adding content. The problem regarding the editing and re-editing is that three people were editing it at the same time, and so concurrent edits were lost. So re-edits and even rollbacks were required to recover these losses.
 In any case, I agree with closing the question and asking the OP to re-ask a more specific one.

Comment: ok. Let me do that then.

Comment: I agree with both of you, and sorry for the roll-back, @Dave, I didn't noticed the changes that you made. The OP can ask new more focused questions if she/he wants.

Comment: ps: maybe we should also delete the answer.

Comment: or our comments.

Comment: feel free to do so :)